# Iphone 5 application launch by another application

Tags: ios5, ios6

I am using following code:

```
int (*openApp)(CFStringRef, Boolean);
void* sbServices = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices", RTLD_LAZY);
openApp= (int(*)(CFStringRef, Boolean))dlsym(sbServices,"SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier");
openApp(CFSTR("com.apple.mobilephone"), FALSE);
dlclose(sbServices);
```

This is working fine in a simulator but on the device it is giving following error:

> com.apple.springboard.launchapplications required to use kern_return_t
>   _SBXXLaunchApplication(mach_port_t, char *, sbs_url_string_t, sbs_property_list_data_t, mach_msg_type_number_t,
>   sbs_property_list_data_t, mach_msg_type_number_t,
>   SBSApplicationLaunchFlags, SBSApplicationLaunchError *, audit_token_t)

Is there any solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 1):

Better use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"]];` You'll need set a custom URL scheme in your second app for that. Check this [tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) or simply do a search with "iphone custom URL schemes". There's a lot of good tutorials.